# In Go Language, how do I unmarshal json to array of object?

Tags: go

I have the following JSON, and I want to parse it into array of class:

```
{
    "1001": {"level":10, "monster-id": 1001, "skill-level": 1, "aimer-id": 301}
    "1002": {"level":12, "monster-id": 1002, "skill-level": 1, "aimer-id": 302}
    "1003": {"level":16, "monster-id": 1003, "skill-level": 2, "aimer-id": 303}
}
```

Here is what i am trying to do but failed:

```
type Monster struct {
    MonsterId  int32
    Level      int32
    SkillLevel int32
    AimerId    int32
}


type MonsterCollection struct {
    Pool map[string]Monster
}

func (mc *MonsterCollection) FromJson(jsonStr string) {
    var data interface{}
    b := []byte(jsonStr)
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &data)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    m := data.(map[string]interface{})

    i := 0
    for k, v := range m {

        monster := new(Monster)
        monster.Level = v["level"]
        monster.MonsterId = v["monster-id"]
        monster.SkillLevel = v["skill-level"]
        monster.AimerId = v["aimer-id"]

        mc.Pool[i] = monster
        i++
    }

}
```

The compiler complain about the  v["level"] 
<< invalid operation. index of type interface().

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This code has many errors in it. To start with, the json isn't valid json. You are missing the commas in between key pairs in your top level object. I added the commas and pretty printed it for you:

```
{
   "1001":{
      "level":10,
      "monster-id":1001,
      "skill-level":1,
      "aimer-id":301
   },
   "1002":{
      "level":12,
      "monster-id":1002,
      "skill-level":1,
      "aimer-id":302
   },
   "1003":{
      "level":16,
      "monster-id":1003,
      "skill-level":2,
      "aimer-id":303
   }
}
```

---

Your next problem (the one you asked about) is that `m := data.(map[string]interface{})` makes `m` a `map[string]interface{}`. That means when you index it such as the `v` in your range loop, the type is `interface{}`. You need to type assert it again with `v.(map[string]interface{})` and then type assert each time you read from the map.

---

I also notice that you next attempt `mc.Pool[i] = monster` when i is an int and mc.Pool is a map[string]Monster. An int is not a valid key for that map.

---

Your data looks very rigid so I would make unmarshall do most of the work for you. Instead of providing it a map[string]interface{}, you can provide it a map[string]Monster.

Here is a quick example. As well as changing how the unmarshalling works, I also added an error return. The error return is useful for finding bugs. That error return is what told me you had invalid json.

```
type Monster struct {
    MonsterId  int32 `json:"monster-id"`
    Level      int32 `json:"level"`
    SkillLevel int32 `json:"skill-level"`
    AimerId    int32 `json:"aimer-id"`
}

type MonsterCollection struct {
    Pool map[string]Monster
}

func (mc *MonsterCollection) FromJson(jsonStr string) error {
    var data = &mc.Pool
    b := []byte(jsonStr)
    return json.Unmarshal(b, data)
}
```

I posted a working example to goplay: http://play.golang.org/p/4EaasS2VLL

Comment: wow, thank you so much. I am just learning the GO lang and still have so much to learn. Your answer is very helpful!

Comment: one more question, is there anyway i can use int32 for the key of the map? the value should be monster-id is this case but when i change the type to int32, the sample code gives error.

Comment: JSON keys must be strings. What you need to do is first parse into a `map[string]Monster` and then copy each monster to a `map[int]Monster`.

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/iJN4P1ImOm this is an example of how to convert it to uint32.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off to one side - you asked for an array of objects when you needed a map

If you need an array (actually a slice)

http://ioblocks.blogspot.com/2014/09/loading-arrayslice-of-objects-from-json.html